# Creating labels and updating a column based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-analysis

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
data = {
    'user_id': [
        '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX',
        '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX', '9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX'
    ],
    'timestamp': [
        1612139269, 1612139665, 1612139579,
        1612141096, 1612143046, 1612143729
    ],
    'type': [
        'productDetails', 'productDetails', 'checkout:confirmation',
        'checkout:confirmation', 'productList', 'checkout:confirmation'
    ],
    'session': [0,1,2,3,4,5],
    'count_session_products': [4, 1, 0, 4, 2, 2],
    'loyalty' : [0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
test_df
```

| user_id | timestamp | type | session | prods | loyalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139269 | productDetails | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139665 | productDetails | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139579 | checkout:confirmation | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612141096 | checkout:confirmation | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143046 | productList | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143729 | checkout:confirmation | 5 | 2 | 0 |

Now I want to create loyalty labels and their conditions such as:

- `first_time_visitor` - any user with session = 0
- `frequent_visitor` - any user with session > 0 and count_session_products > 0
- `first_time_customer` - first time checkout:confirmation appears in the type column
- `repeat_customer` - second time of checkout:confirmation appears in the type column
- `loyal_customer` - third time of checkout:confirmation appears in the type column

I have already have the conditions for `first_time_visitor` and `frequent_visitor` but I am having trouble creating `first_time_customer`, `repeat_customer` and `loyal_customer` labels.

Conditions for `first_time_visitor` and `frequent_visitor` are as follows:

```
test_df['loyalty'] = np.where((test_df['session'] > 0) & ((test_df['type'] != 'checkout:confirmation')), 'frequent_visitor', None)
test_df.loc[test_df['session'] == 0, 'loyalty'] = 'first_time_visitor'
```

which gives me a dataframe looking like this:

| user_id | timestamp | type | session | prods | loyalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139269 | productDetails | 0 | 4 | first_time_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139665 | productDetails | 1 | 1 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139579 | checkout:confirmation | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612141096 | checkout:confirmation | 3 | 4 | 0 |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143046 | productList | 4 | 2 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143729 | checkout:confirmation | 5 | 2 | 0 |

I have had a couple of ideas only, one being to use `first_valid_index()` or `argmax()` to find the index and somehow use that in a condition to create the `first_time_customer` label. But I am not sure how to implement these conditions.

```
(test_df.type.values == 'checkout:confirmation').argmax()
test_df[test_df.type == 'checkout:confirmation'].first_valid_index()
```

In the end, I would expect my loyalty column to look like this:

| user_id | timestamp | type | session | prods | loyalty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139269 | productDetails | 0 | 4 | first_time_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139665 | productDetails | 1 | 1 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612139579 | checkout:confirmation | 2 | 0 | first_time_customer |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612141096 | checkout:confirmation | 3 | 4 | repeat_customer |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143046 | productList | 4 | 2 | frequent_visitor |
| 9EPWZVMNP6D6KWX | 1612143729 | checkout:confirmation | 5 | 2 | loyal_customer |

Any suggestions and help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this for a live application / is the data live? Or do you have some old dataset and you are trying to update when the user became this or that loyalty? If it is for some live application, it may be easier to update loyalty for the user on a separate table when the loyalty changes, rather than in this way. That said, this can surely still be done.

Comment: Can you give some suggestion/examples as to how this could be done? Because I have been stuck.
And right now it's just a basic analysis, later on it will be used on live data.

Comment: would depend a lot on the application and model and a lot more. and i was thinking like if you are developing the entire application and controlling everything with it, rather than getting live data from somewhere else. then when a person makes a purchase, you could look up what their loyalty level is where you have that saved and just increment it and save the new loyalty. then whenever you have a purchase you aren't looping through the whole table counting purchases, but just comparing against their most recent loyalty level.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that would be:

```
mask = test_df.type.eq('checkout:confirmation')
mask = mask & mask.cumsum().le(3) 
test_df.loc[mask, 'loyalty'] = (
    ['first_time_customer', 'repeat_customer', 'loyal_customer'][:mask.sum()]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

edit: my original post had the first loop on `n` in reverse, I don't think we need that or it helps... i also updated it so that we don't count previous occurrences of checkout:confirmation but instead just add 1 to the last checkout:confirmation count, so we are able to skip running through as many lines.

I think I was able to get a solution that uses a double-reverse loop over the dataframe. Probably not the most efficient thing in the world, but should work...

It uses the idea that each checkout seems to move the user up a level, and so we use integers and just add 1 to the loyalty before mapping those integers to words. Since loyalty-level = 3 is the highest, we are able to bail out of the loop early if we get to that level 3.

This doesn't do anything with the visitor status, so you'll want to make sure that your two methods work together for that.

```py
df['l'] = 0 # makes a new temp column in the df to store our loyalty calcs
for n in range(len(df)): # start to loop through the dataframe
    l = 0 # set the loyalty level to 0
    if df['type'][n] == 'checkout:confirmation': # only do this for checkouts
            l = 1 # if it is a checkout, the loyalty is now 1 (might go up)
            for i in reversed(range(n)): # start looking at the rows above the current one for more checkouts
                    if df['user_id'][n] == df['user_id'][i] and df['type'][i] == 'checkout:confirmation': # make sure the userid matches as well as the above row is checkout
                            l = min(df['l'][i]+1,3) # if our new loyalty would be > 3, just set it to 3, which is the max
                            break 
            df['l'][n] = l # set the loyalty level in row n to l

df['loyalty'] = df['l'].map({1:'first_time_customer',2:'frequent_customer',3:'loyal_customer'}) # maps the integers to text for the loyalty. gives NaN for the non-purchase rows.
```